# "Complex" geometry - UV Mapping

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]any ideas why the UV map is not showing up at all with this object? Its a Shell like geometry (hollow on the inside). Generated through simplicity modelling in Grasshopper.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: hello, we don't see any picture, please give more informations

Comment: @moonboots sorry, its late in Zurich ^^. I hadnt added the picture. Now it should show up.

Comment: have you unwrapped?

Comment: also select all in Edit mode, otherwise you won't see the UV in the UV Editor, unless you activate the sync option

Comment: Go into edit mode, press `A` to select all verts, then press `U` to unwrap (might be a different command), then select one of the options

Comment: You guys are completely right, thanks a  lot :)! I have gotten one to work. Is there a way to copy the uv unwrap/ uv projection to the other objects (of the exact same geometry)?

Comment: @ user134222 you can try that: select the objects you want to unwrap, shift select the object you have already unwrapped, and press Ctrl L > Tranfer UV Maps

Comment: thansk again :)!